# Count sum of multiples of a number below N with O(1) complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, factors

**We are given two numbers M and N. We need to count the sum of all the integers below N, which are divisible by M.**

Is it possible to solve with O(1) complexity?

I know it is a very simple program and can be easily done with a loop. But I was wondering if it is possible to apply some kind of formula or something to directly count the sum of numbers which are divisible by M below N.

Comment: What makes you think this could be possible? In other words: you are just dropping a requirement here; but we expect you to show us that you tried solving the problem yourself.

Comment: If we divide the number N by M, then we get the total count of numbers divisible by M below N. So, all the numbers would be in a progression of M. I ain't very good at math so I asked here. It would really be helpful if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: That's what two of us have done. Is neither answer helpful?

Comment: yes it is correct. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there is an O(1) solution:

First exploit *integer arithmetic* to compute `n = N / M`. `n` is then the number of terms in an *arithmetic progression* with first term and common difference equal to `M`.

The sum (which comes from the formula for an arithmetic progression) is then

`n * (1 + n) * M / 2`

For example, consider N = 23, and M = 5. You're after 5 + 10 + 15 + 20 which is 50. The closed form solution evaluates to 4 * 5 * 5 / 2 which is also 50.

Comment: Ok then something more difficult , what about the case we have two numbers m1 and m2 (lets say on the previous example M=5 M2=3 and N=23 ,and we want to count 15 onl once),then we can easy add multiples of three multiples of 5 and remove multiples of 15 ,but what if we have M1,M2,M3...M100 etc

Answer (score 3):

```
L:=floor(M/N)

M + 2*M + 3*M + ... + L*M 

= M (1+2+3+4+...+L)
```

this can be solved with the [wikipedia summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

```
= M*(L*(L+1)/2)
```

This can be calculated in O(1)